# Using Swift closure with Objective-C framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am using the MCSwipeTableViewCell framework for swipe-able tableviewcells. One of the completion blocks inside a `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function looks like this:

```
[cell setSwipeGestureWithView:checkView color:greenColor mode:MCSwipeTableViewCellModeSwitch state:MCSwipeTableViewCellState1 completionBlock:^(MCSwipeTableViewCell *cell, MCSwipeTableViewCellState state, MCSwipeTableViewCellMode mode) {
      // run some function call
}];
```

I used a Bridging-Header file to import the framework into my Swift project and am attempting to use that same completion block in Swift. This is what I have:

```
cell.setSwipeGestureWithView(crossView, color: UIColor.colorFromRGB(RED), mode: MCSwipeTableViewCellMode.Switch, state:MCSwipeTableViewCellState.State1, completionBlock: { (cell: MCSwipeTableViewCell!, state: MCSwipeTableViewCellState!, mode: MCSwipeTableViewCellMode!) -> Void in
    self.runSomeFunction();
});
```

The problem is, it crashes everytime I run `self.runSomeFunction()` even though the function call is implemented. The error is

unrecognized selector

```
sent to instance 0x165c7390
2014-07-07 16:23:14.809 pong[3950:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM runSomeFunction]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x165c7390'
```

I know the completion block works because I can NSLog from it and it displays something, but attempting to access self always results in a crash.

Any ideas? Should I not be trying to access self?

=== Update ===

Mainly what I'm trying to figure out is how to access `self` within a Swift closure. It keeps throwing a bad access error.

*Here is the code that is running*

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
{
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userCell") as MCSwipeTableViewCell!

    if !cell {
        cell = MCSwipeTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "userCell")
     }
    cell.setSwipeGestureWithView(crossView, color: UIColor.colorFromRGB(RED), mode: MCSwipeTableViewCellMode.Switch, state:MCSwipeTableViewCellState.State1, completionBlock: { (cell: MCSwipeTableViewCell!, state: MCSwipeTableViewCellState!, mode: MCSwipeTableViewCellMode!) -> Void in
        self.runSomething();
    });
    return cell
}

 func runSomething()
{
    NSLog("hey there");
}
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. It's not a compile-time issue.

Comment: Yeah adding a return void() does nothing. It still just crashes there and now doesn't print anything other than exc_bad_access.

Comment: "MyClass.runSomeFunction()" is not Objective-C, and very different from "self.runSomeFunction()"

Comment: Ah sorry, was just doing some ruby and got confused. I updated the question and removed that part. I'm trying to call a private method on the uiviewcontroller

Comment: `-[__NSArrayM runSomeFunction]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` tells me that you think you're accessing `self` but actually accessing an `NS(Mutable)Array`. Maybe a memory issue?

Comment: Well, I'm not getting that error anymore. I tried passing in a strong reference to self in the block, but even that crashes without any notable error except EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a [Capture List](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-XID_66!) to use `self` inside a Closure like this:

```
cell.setSwipeGestureWithView(crossView, color: UIColor.colorFromRGB(RED), mode: MCSwipeTableViewCellMode.Switch, state:MCSwipeTableViewCellState.State1) {
    [unowned self]
    cell, state, mode in
    self.runSomething()
}
```

Currently `[unowned self]` may crash sometimes so for the time being use `[weak self]` and inside your closure unwrap `self` like: `self!.doSomething()`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to weakify `self` by: `[weak self]`. And after it inside block try to check if `self` is not `nil`:

```
if let weakSelf = self {
   // do whatever you want with the self
}
```