# "Unrecognized selector sent to instance" with addTarget(_:action:)

Tags: swift

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong... Also because in other parts of my app the same thing works... But let me explain now my problem. I have an object where I configure a UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer with `addTarget(_:action:)`, like this:

```
swipeFromEdge = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer()

swipeFromEdge.addTarget(self, action: "handlePanFromEdge")
swipeFromEdge.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
swipeFromEdge.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
swipeFromEdge.edges = .Left

appDelegate.navController.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeFromEdge)
```

After this config, in the same class I add this method:

```
func handlePanFromEdge() {
 ...
}
```

Everything seems fine, but every time I swipe from the left edge of the screen the app blocks with this explanation:

```
-[__NSArrayM handlePanFromEdge]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x145967f0
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: looks like the same error here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619179/using-swift-closure-with-objective-c-framework Unfortunately there isn't an answer. I'd try the dev forums. It may be a bug in the latest beta

Comment: Where is this code located?

Comment: My code is located in a custom object that implements the UINavigationController delegate. I use this object for custom transitions of UINavigationController. I add a gesture recognizer to create an interactive transition.

Comment: And yes, my app sometimes crashes directly at compile time... Often I need to recompile my app several times to get it work... Any ideas?

Comment: Old question, but this is probably because you class does not inherit from NSObject. You need this for target/action to work... Been bitten repeatedly by this one.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue.  Try putting a action into a Selector and put a colon after the selector value:

```
swipeFromEdge.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handlePanFromEdge:"))
```